# how to run dependent jobs if dependency is skipped?

Tags: github-actions

If I have 2 jobs, where one must run after the other, but the former can be skipped due to some condition, how do I ensure that the second job runs if its condition is true? (I am using https://github.com/marketplace/actions/paths-changes-filter to determine whether a job should run based on whether a change has happened in its subdirectory).

```
jobs:
  job1:
    if: some_condition_1

  job2:
    needs: job1
    if: some_condition_2
```

So, if `some_condition_1` is false, then `job1` will not fire. How do I ensure that if `some_condition_2` is true, that `job2` runs if `job1` is skipped? In the above setup, `job2` does not fire if `job1` is skipped. Additionally, `job2` needs to run after `job1` if `job1` does actually run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `jobs.<job_id>.if` conditional - [doc's](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-conditions-to-control-job-execution#overview) - along with status check functions `success()`, `always()` or `failure()` for a specific job - [doc's](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#status-check-functions) - to create a separate logic for job control simply using `&&` instead of using `need` for prerequisite jobs.

Edit with little example:

```yaml
name: demo 

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ 'some_condition_1'=='not_true' }}
    steps:
      - name: Step for job1
        run: echo Hello from job1! 
  job2:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: job1
    if: ${{ always()  && 'some_condition_2'=='some_condition_2' }}
    steps:
      - name: Step for job2
        run: echo Hello from job2!
```

Comment: How does `job2` refer to the status of `job1`? I don't see a syntax for that and I can't use an output as those are only made available to downstream jobs that use `needs` to establish a dependency (https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/defining-outputs-for-jobs).

Comment: I've added simple example above...

Answer (score 1):

@Michal's answer will run job2 after job1 if `some_condition_2` is satisfied, regardless of the status of job1. You can ensure that job2 runs if job1 is skipped and *does not run* if job1 fails or is cancelled with the following modification.

```
name: demo 

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ 'some_condition_1'=='not_true' }}
    steps:
      - name: Step for job1
        run: echo Hello from job1! 
  job2:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: job1
    if: ${{ ! failure() && ! cancelled() && 'some_condition_2'=='some_condition_2' }}
    steps:
      - name: Step for job2
        run: echo Hello from job2!
```

Comment: shouldn't that be `!failure()` instead of `!success()`?

Comment: @Matthias, you are correct. I revised my answer.